# DockPanel resize objects inside

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dockpanel

I want to make my objects in `DockPanel` expand automatically when the window is resized, currently they only change their position.

My XAML:

```
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="405">
        <Image Source="/myImage.png"></Image>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button Width="406"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DockPanel` is primarily intended to position elements relative to each other, but it does not distribute the available space with special constraints for each child proportionally.

> The `SetDock` method **changes the position of an element relative to other elements** within the same container. Alignment properties, such as `HorizontalAlignment`, change the position of an element relative to its parent element.

It only allows you to let the last child added to take any remaining space.

> If you set the `LastChildFill` property to `true`, which is the default setting, **the last child element of a `DockPanel` always fills the remaining space**, regardless of any other dock value that you set on the last child element.

That means you could let your `ScrollViewer` stretch, but not the `Button` and vice-versa. To do this, make the control that should take the remaining space the last one in the `DockPanel`, e.g.:

```
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
   <Button Width="406" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
   <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <Image Source="/myImage.png"/>
   </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

The default value of `LastChildFill` is `true`, so you do not have to specify it explicitly.

---

A different approach to fulfill your requirements is to use a [`Grid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) instead. A `Grid` can take proportional sizing constraints (star `*` sizing) for any row and column.

> Columns and rows that are defined within a `Grid` can take advantage of Star sizing to distribute remaining space proportionally. When **Star** is selected as the height or width of a row or column, that column or row **receives a weighted proportion of the remaining available space**. This is in contrast to `Auto`, which distributes space evenly based on the size of the content that is within a column or row.

This allows you to specify precisely how the available space is distributed.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="405*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="406*"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <Image Source="/myImage.png"/>
   </ScrollViewer>
   <Button Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```